# Wordpress - Contact Form 7 before_send_mail

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have create a table on db and I want to verify the "code" from db from the form before sending and it doesn't work.

this is my code.

```
  function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) 
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ( $form_to_DB ){
            $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
        }
        $name = $formData['code'];
        $nom = $formData['nom'];
        $prenom = $formData['prenom'];
        $cle = $formData['cle'];
       $req = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb-> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) from        $wpdb->members WHERE code='".$formData["code"]."'"));
        $resultat =$req->get_result("SELECT * FROM wp_members WHERE  code='".$_POST['code']."'");

        if($resultat[0] == 0) 
          {
            echo'<script language="javascript">alert("code Incorrect");</script>';
          }
        else{       
        $wpdb->insert( 'wp_members', array( 'code' =>  $name,'nom'=>$nom,'prenom'=>$prenom ), array( '%s','%s','%s' ) );
        echo'<script language="javascript">alert("code ");</script>';
       }

    //$wpdb->insert( 'wp_members', array( 'code' => $name,'nom'=>$nom,'prenom'=>$prenom ), array( '%s','%s','%s' ) );
    }
remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $form_to_DB ){
        $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
    }
    $name = $formData['code'];
    $nom = $formData['nom'];
    $prenom = $formData['prenom'];
    $cle = $formData['cle'];       
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_members', array( 'code' =>  $name,'nom'=>$nom,'prenom'=>$prenom ), array( '%s','%s','%s' ) );
    //echo'<script language="javascript">alert("code ");</script>'; 
    //$wpdb->insert( 'wp_members', array( 'code' => $name,'nom'=>$nom,'prenom'=>$prenom ), array( '%s','%s','%s' ) );
}
remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );


function custom_code_validation($result,$tag){
    global $wpdb;
    $type = $tag['type'];
    $name = $tag['name'];

    $req = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb-> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) from $wpdb->members WHERE code='".$_POST[$name]."'"));
    $resultat =$req->get_result("SELECT * FROM wp_members WHERE  code='".$_POST[$name]."'");

    if($name == 'code') {
        $code = isset( $_POST[$name] ) ? trim( $_POST[$name] ) : '';     

        if($resultat[0] == 0) { 
          $result->invalidate( $tag, "code Incorrect" );
        } 
    }
    return $result;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text','custom_code_validation', 10, 2);
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_code_validation', 10, 2);
```

Comment: not working the form still loading and i don't get the email :S

and for the insert.. i just put in to verify the condition

Comment: still not working the loading icon is running and there's no mail

Comment: Im using this code working fine. form field name is correct?

Comment: the same thing :/
can we teamviewer or something like that ?